# Refer two database tables in same query in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two different databases and I have to run a query where I am going to join tables from both databases in a single query. My query goes like this:

```
SELECT mm.* FROM tbl1 mm INNER JOIN tbl2 t ON mm.module_id=t.module_id WHERE mm.module_name NOT IN(SELECT module_name FROM tbl3)"
```

Here *tbl1* and *tbl2* are in one database and *tbl3* is in the second database. Is it possible to run this query without HARD CODING the database names before the table names? I created common files **global_config1.php** and **global_config2.php** which have the database constants and other php database connection constants and am using `require_once(global_config1.php)` and `require_once(global_config2.php)` but the query fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My purpose was resolved by separating the queries and the database connection string variables. So to run a query on one database, I entered separate connection string variables in mysql_query(). This helped fetch the data from both databases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Database1.TableA.ColumnA1, Database1.TableA.ColumnA2,
Database2.TableB.ColumnB1, Database2.TableB.ColumnB2
FROM Database1.TableA
INNER JOIN
Database2.TableB ON
Database1.TableA.ColumnA3 = Database2.TableB.ColumnB3
```

Now, you will see the complete result in a single row. In case, the column names are same in both databases, you will see the column names same in the result and it will be impossible to get the value in PHP because 2 or more column name is same. To accomplish this, lets write another query

Answer (score 0):

you can use two different database to fetch a record, for this you have two database object.

try this,

```
<?php 
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

      $con1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test1");

     $query = "SELECT mm.* FROM test.tbl1 mm INNER JOIN test.tbl2 t ON mm.module_id=t.module_id WHERE mm.module_name NOT IN(SELECT module_name FROM test1.tbl3)"
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and shouldn't be used any more.

Answer (score 0):

For CI
$query = $this ->db->query("SELECT * FROM Table-1 WHERE id = (SELECT qid FROM Table-2  where post_status ='active' AND post_type= 'quick') ");
return $query->result_array();

Comment: SELECT qid FROM Table-2 where post_status ='active' AND post_type= 'quick') 
This is for one table.
"SELECT * FROM Table-1 WHERE id = * 
This is for second table.